# Is it true that the continuous $2\pi$-periodic function is almost everywhere differentiable?

Tags: continuity, periodic-functions, almost-everywhere, absolute-continuity

Is it true that the continuous $2\pi$-periodic function is almost everywhere differentiable (how to verify this statement)? Is that an absolute continuous function?
Could someone provide an explanation for mean of almost everywhere differentiable function. I have not been able to distinghuisd "almost everywhere" and "everywhere" of this context.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

The famous counterexample https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function is continuous and periodic, but nowhere differentiable.

A sufficient condition for almost everywhere differentiability (which means differentiability outside of a set of Lebesgue measure zero) is to have bounded variation.

Comment: Thank you.  In this context, what are the minimum requirements for the decay of the Fourier coefficients of a function faster than $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: I am not sure sorry. I guess this would deserve a question where you state precisely what you need in the end !

Answer (score 0):

A continuous periodic function  can be nowhere differentiable.